# Laravel: Query Exception

Tags: php, sql, database, laravel-5.3

> Array to string conversion (SQL: insert into `RegisterStudent` (`LRN`,
>   `dateOfBirth`, `sex`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (1234,
>   1996-02-10, Female, 2017-10-26 05:30:32, 2017-10-26 05:30:32))

[image]

StudentController store content

```
public function store(Request $request){

     //validation
    $this->validate($request, [
        'LRN' => 'required|max:100',
    ]);

    $student = New Student;
    $student->LRN = $request->input('LRN');
    $student->dateOfBirth = $request->input('dateOfBirth');
    $student->sex = $request->input('sex');

    $student->save();

    return redirect()->back();
}
```

Comment: You are sending `LRN` and `sex` as an array. Show your html code

Comment: Lois Arce, check out madalinivascu's answer. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Change the following:

```
$student->sex = $request->input('sex')[0];
```

the input seems to be a array so you need the value at [0]
or remove the [] in your input name to use in php `$request->input('sex')`

Comment: How could you decide that its `sex` but not any other field?

Comment: @HimanshuUpadhyay if you look in the screenshot,in the white list the second item you can see `array('Female')`